# Can I create an Android app that uses the Spotify Web API without having the user install Spotify?

Tags: android, flutter, spotify

It looks like to use the Spotify API on android, I need to use the Spotify Android SDK. This requires the user of my app to have Spotify installed! I just want to get small things like genres and user playlists for my app, I don't want playback capabilities.
Is there a way to do this using the Spotify web API instead?

I tried using the Spotify web API, and was expecting it to work as it was, but all the documentation asks you to use the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can indeed use the Spotify Web API to access data such as genres and user playlists without requiring the user to have the Spotify app installed.

```
var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists'),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
    },
  );
```

Provide the access token that you can get from spotify developer. Handle rest of the behaviour of success or failure of response.